# MVC project stops debugging right after opening Chrome pane

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Visual Studio project, and when trying to run the project in Google Chrome, it stops debugging right after opening a new pane in Google Chrome.

I suspect this has something to do with IIS Express, but I have no idea where to begin when searching for this issue. I tried searching online, but without any luck. It doesn't seem like a common problem.

I have a solution with multiple projects, and my MVC project is dependent on some of these projects. It all builds just fine, and my MVC project is set as the startup project.

I'd love to give you more information, but this is all I have. I find this quite disturbing as I cannot test the code immediately after writing it, but I have to manually merge this into a colleagues solution to actually test.

Any guideline, tips and tricks, or possible solution is much appreciated.

*Note: this issue has been present after zipping the project from a colleagues PC, then copying to my own and unzipping.*

*Extra note: When opening the solution in VS 2015 it asks to convert the project to a newer version. This doesn't happen on my colleagues PC, and we run the same version of VS. This strikes me as pretty odd, but I didn't think more about it. It does fail to convert 4 projects, but none of these are added as references in my MVC project.*

**EDIT**
The following gets printed to my output window:

> The program '[13188] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The program '[13188] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

**EDIT 2**
I decided to try and run this is Internet explorer instead of Google Chrome. Now the project is actually running is VS, but my IIS Express is not started, therefore I cannot connect to my URL (*as such doesn't exists unless IIS Express is actually running*).

Just tried Microsoft Edge as well. Same behavior as Internet Explorer.

**EDIT 3**
Apparently my colleague is using VS Enterprise 2015, and I'm only using VS Pro 2015. The solution we bought needed to use VS Enterprise for some strange reason. This is why it runs perfectly on my colleagues environment.

Comment: Any output in the debug/output pane?  One thing to try is to disable Browser Link and see if that helps.  I've had it ruin me a few times.

Comment: Yuck, a colleague came to me yesterday telling me about a similar problem. We haven't figured this one out yet, he resorted to Firefox.

Comment: Offtop, but, why not put all stuff into some repository and try fetch it from there? Instead of zipping

Comment: I got problem like this once but done nothing to solve it really, restored project data from VCS in new folder, removed old one

Comment: @DanilGholtsman We're just about to do that, but this is a solution bought from another company, that we just need to add some custom functionality to. Zipping is just temporary

Comment: @Mitch Yes there is. Will update my SO

Comment: @Mitch I tried disabling Browser Link, but nothing changes. Still the same issue: stops debugging without any sort of message.

Comment: @Detilium, Do you get any latest information in your side? One idea is that you could reset your VS settings, and then create a simple MVC app, debug it again, if it works well, you could create a blank solution, and then add all previous project files to this blank solution, clean and build the solution, debug it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > When opening the solution in VS 2015 it asks to convert the project to a newer version. This doesn't happen on my colleagues PC, and we run the same version of VS.

It seems that the project was updated, if possible, please compare your VS version with the pc of your colleagues, for example, click VS Help menu->About Visual Studio and compare the version number.

Not debugging your app, just run it using start without debugging, how about the result? We have to make sure that it was not the project issue.

> > The program '[13188] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> >
> > The program '[13188] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

As you said that project was updated, please close the Visual studio and delete .vs configuration folder which is inside the root of project folder and It’s a hidden. Re-open your project, view the debugging result.

[image]

Comment: Updated my SO. My colleague is running VS Enterprise 2015, I'm only using VS Pro 2015

Comment: @Detilium, Not very sure that whether it is related to your VS since they are different versions, but just to make this issue clearly, how about creating a new simple MVC app in your VS? Could you run your app using "start without debugging"? Please compare your project property with your colleagues' in VS, just right click the project->properties->Build/Web in solution explorer window, and then compare them in different VS machines, maybe you could find more useful information there.

Comment: This seems to be the most correct answer. I borrowed a colleagues Enterprise license, and tried running with debugging. Apparently some dependency injection causes some error, and I suspect that this is what crashes the application. It's strange that this doesn't give me an exception, but at least it's something. Thank you for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the very limited information, my guess is that your application does not start up as expected. You could try logging/debugging start up process to see if the application actually runs after you run it. The output tells your application just stops after being run:

```
The program '[13188] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[13188] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0)
```

It means your application is not running. Put some logging into start up code and see how far it goes and try to catch any exceptions that might be crashing your app.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and was getting same error

```
 The program '[13188] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Try to change the setting in visual studio

Go to Tool-> Options->Debugging->General and uncheck the option "Requires source files to be exactly match the original version"

I hope this will help.